# What is a high thread count in IIS7 Worker Process Indicative Of?

Tags: iis, deadlock, worker-process

I'm currently experiencing some problems with my server.

I have a pool which is consistently deadlocking. It is an IIS7 Worker Process in Integrated mode.

I've recently noticed that in Task Manager > Processes; the thread count is unusually high. (running up to 450 threads compared to the 50 of any other worker process)

Is this typically indicative of a particular problem or am I left shooting into the dark to try and fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we were experiencing a recursive redirect error due to a '/' in our query string.